# powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command

Tags: powershell, github, bamboo

on my bamboo remote machine when I build the plan it's failing

I tried to check paths in env and everything seems fine

```
Failing task since return code of [powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command C:\Users\xxx\bamboo-agent-home\temp\AA-GO354-ET-38-ScriptBuildTask-8740122041187922133.ps1] was -1 while expected 0
Finished task 'Set Github test status to completed' with result: Failed
```

Comment: Please add more information. What is the content of the build task script `AA-GO354-ET-38-ScriptBuildTask-8740122041187922133.ps1`?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] rules.

Answer (score 0):

With just the title of the task, you might need to add a line to use TLS 1.2 in your script if you are using Invoke-WebRequest.

I grabbed the Github Status PS script I'm using to report statuses and it looks like this. Obviously, fill in your own `__GITHUB_REPO__` and `__GITHUB_TOKEN__`

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.github.com/repos/__GITHUB_REPO__/statuses/${bamboo.repository.revision.number} -Headers @{"Authorization"="[__GITHUB_TOKEN__]"} -UseBasicParsing -Method POST -Body @'
{"state":"success","description":"The Bamboo CI build was successful.","target_url":"${bamboo.buildResultsUrl}"}
'@
```